# Is there any functionality provided in Salesforce for generating wizard using default provided functionality ?

Tags: force.com, controller

Is there any functionality provided in Salesforce for generating wizard  using default provided functionality ? I don't want to generate custom controller  for getting this functionality.

Comment: If it helps you https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Visual_Workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for **Visual Workflow** (Flows)

Visual process tools and wizards make it second nature to add complex business logic to your apps, and to make changes as your business evolves. Visual Workflow, built using Force.com's Cloud Flow Designer, lets you visually string together one or more forms, business rules, and calls to backend APIs to implement a complete business process without writing code.

Visual Workflow enables you to automate business processes across your organization. For example:

1. call scripting for inbound or outbound call centers
2. diagnostics &troubleshooting guides
3. guided data entry processes to reduce errors & training costs
4. product configuration
5. sales quotations
6. guided selling with sales methodologies
7. employee on-boarding

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_designer_flow_create.htm&language=en_US
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=vpm_admin_flow_detail.htm&language=en_US
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Visual_Workflow